# creating three arrays to fill with c style strings

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, c-strings

Are teacher has given us an assignment using C++ and since i am not seeking for the solution to do the whole program i will ask only for info based on what im struggling with.

ive made my program allow the user to choose what file they want to open. The file that is to be opened will contain stateInitials, miles, and numberOfShelters. Each one is followed with a space.

looks like this

wv 4.0 3
nc 32.7 4
sc 43.2 10

I need to read in first the stateInitials and put them in its own array and then put the miles in its own array and the numberOfShelters in its own array. There are 16 lines of the same repeating pattern so the stateInitials array should hold 16 and the same with the other two arrays. I CAN NOT USE VECTORS. I CAN NOT USE STRINGS. can only use C STYLE STRINGS. I can not figure out how to create an array that holds 16 c style strings. Ive googled it about 8 hours now and the only solutions are beyond the knowledge of what are teacher would expect us to know. We did cover 2 dimensional arrays and i tried using them but got a lousy result. I need only a solution to create an array holding c strings  and as much explanation as possible so i can understand your method thank you.

Comment: Use dynamic memory: `new` `new[]` `malloc` `realloc`. Also, C-Style strings are just arrays of non-0 char terminated with a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// have an array for each of the fields
// stateInitials is two-dimensional as it stores many characters for each state
const char stateInitials[Num_States][Max_State_Size];
int miles[Max_States];
int numberOfShelters[Max_States];

// work through the input a state at a time...
for (int i = 0; i < Num_States; ++i)
    // if you can't get a space-delimited state name, miles and numberOfShelters, fail
    if (!(stream.getline(stateInitials[i], Max_State_Size, ' ') &&
          stream >> miles >> numberOfShelters)
    {
        std::cerr << "bad input for state # " << i + 1 << '\n';
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

If you were allowed to use vectors and strings this would be much cleaner.  You need to create an `ifstream` (which I've assumed is called "`stream`") beforehand, and create the constants for maximum array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *stringArr[N] = new char*[N];
stringArray[x] = "hello";
```

Is this not what you are looking for?